# how to add an array element to a textbox that isnt already in the array created in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I'm trying to make a phone book where the user can enter a number and a name which gets stored in an array. then I'm trying to get the names to appear in separate text boxes in another scene but because the array doesn't already have the name it wont work properly. This is the code i am using.

```
    contact5.text=myNames[4];
```

but because there are only 4 names in the array it wont play properly

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bulletproof it with the most simple test:

```
contact5.text = myNames.length >= 5 ? myNames[4] : 'empty';
// note 5 > 4, because of 0 index
```

Very hacky, but should do the trick. Better option is to structure your code properly so it loops through the values and sets the ones that are not empty, and just clears the others.

p.s.
Just in case you are not familiar with it - this is a short code for `if-else` statement.